# propel generator failing due to could not instantiate class XXX

Tags: php, generator, propel

I have been building a new project for the last 2 months, I probably have ran the propel-gen om 10-15 times without fail until the other day. I did a quick pear upgrade and then propel-gen om and seem to get an error i dont understand.

I have tried on two windows machines and one linux machine and I keep getting the same error.

First off does anyone have a complete project which works,  that I can try and build to rule out the possibility this is phing related.

anything obvious from this?

my build.properties looks like this

```
#start of file
# Database driver

propel.project = Cream

propel.targetPackage = {propel.project}


propel.database = mysql

project.home = C:\xampp\htdocs\Cream
project.build = ${project.home}/propel

propel.output.dir = ${project.home}
propel.php.dir = ${propel.output.dir}/ActiveRecord
propel.phpconf.dir = ${propel.output.dir}/ActiveRecord/config
propel.sql.dir = ${project.build}/sql


propel.database.url = mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cream
propel.database.user = root
propel.database.password = 

propel.addGenericAccessors = true
propel.addGenericMutators = true
propel.addTimeStamp = true
propel.addIncludes = false
#end of file
```

error message is a lot of

```
could not instantiate class propelSQLTask
could not instantiate class propelSchemaReverseTask
could not instantiate class propelDataSQLTask
```

etc etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the issue turned out to be propel does not support the latest phing you must downgrade your phing in order to solve the issue

```
pear uninstall phing/phing
pear install phing/phing-2.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor clarification - the incompatibility is the other way around. Propel intends to work with the latest version of Phing, but the latest version of Phing broke backwards compatibility. I understand this will be rectified in a new version of Phing -- which may already be released.